# ¿Cómo pueden funcionar los paréntesis en calculadora Java (Android)?

Tags: java, android

Estoy haciendo una calculadora y al usar las funciones del paréntesis y la de la raíz cuadrada no logro hacer que funcione el calculo .

Ejemplo: `2(2+2) debería dar 8`, pero me da error cuando intento calcularlo.

Código java :

```
package com.example.liantonypozo.prueba;

import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.icu.text.DecimalFormat;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.liantonypozo.prueba.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    private static final char ADDITION = '+';
    private static final char SUBTRACTION = '-';
    private static final char MULTIPLICATION = '*';
    private static final char DIVISION = '/';

    private char CURRENT_ACTION;

    private double valueOne = Double.NaN;
    private double valueTwo;

    private DecimalFormat decimalFormat;



    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##########");

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);



        binding.buttonParentesis1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + "(");
            }
        });


        binding.buttonParentesis2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + ")");
            }
        });



        binding.buttonDot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + ".");
            }
        });

        binding.buttonZero.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + "0");
            }
        });

        binding.buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + "1");
            }
        });

        binding.buttonTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + "2");
            }
        });

        binding.buttonThree.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + "3");
            }
        });

        binding.buttonFour.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + "4");
            }
        });

        binding.buttonFive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + "5");
            }
        });

        binding.buttonSix.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + "6");
            }
        });

        binding.buttonSeven.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + "7");
            }
        });

        binding.buttonEight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + "8");
            }
        });

        binding.buttonNine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + "9");
            }
        });

        binding.buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                computeCalculation();
                CURRENT_ACTION = ADDITION;
                binding.infoTextView.setText(decimalFormat.format(valueOne) + "+");
                binding.editText.setText(null);
            }
        });

        binding.buttonSubtract.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                computeCalculation();
                CURRENT_ACTION = SUBTRACTION;
                binding.infoTextView.setText(decimalFormat.format(valueOne) + "-");
                binding.editText.setText(null);
            }
        });

        binding.buttonMultiply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                computeCalculation();
                CURRENT_ACTION = MULTIPLICATION;
                binding.infoTextView.setText(decimalFormat.format(valueOne) + "*");
                binding.editText.setText(null);
            }
        });

        binding.buttonDivide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                computeCalculation();
                CURRENT_ACTION = DIVISION;
                binding.infoTextView.setText(decimalFormat.format(valueOne) + "/");
                binding.editText.setText(null);
            }
        });

        binding.buttonEqual.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                computeCalculation();
                binding.infoTextView.setText(binding.infoTextView.getText().toString() +
                        decimalFormat.format(valueTwo) + " = " + decimalFormat.format(valueOne));
                valueOne = Double.NaN;
                CURRENT_ACTION = '0';
            }
        });

        binding.buttonClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(binding.editText.getText().length() > 0) {
                    CharSequence currentText = binding.editText.getText();
                    binding.editText.setText(currentText.subSequence(0, currentText.length()-1));
                }
                else {
                    valueOne = Double.NaN;
                    valueTwo = Double.NaN;
                    binding.editText.setText("");
                    binding.infoTextView.setText("");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void computeCalculation() {
        if(!Double.isNaN(valueOne)) {
            valueTwo = Double.parseDouble(binding.editText.getText().toString());
            binding.editText.setText(null);

            if(CURRENT_ACTION == ADDITION)
                valueOne = this.valueOne + valueTwo;
            else if(CURRENT_ACTION == SUBTRACTION)
                valueOne = this.valueOne - valueTwo;
            else if(CURRENT_ACTION == MULTIPLICATION)
                valueOne = this.valueOne * valueTwo;
            else if(CURRENT_ACTION == DIVISION)
                valueOne = this.valueOne / valueTwo;
        }
        else {
            try {
                valueOne = Double.parseDouble(binding.editText.getText().toString());
            }
            catch (Exception e){}
        }



    }
}
```

xml:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/activity_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context="com.sample.foo.samplecalculator.MainActivity">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/infoTextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/infoTextView"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:lines="2"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonSeven"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/editText"
                    android:text="7"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonEight"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/editText"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonSeven"
                    android:text="8"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonNine"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/editText"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonEight"
                    android:text="9"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonFour"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/buttonSeven"
                    android:text="4"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonFive"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@id/buttonEight"
                    android:layout_below="@id/buttonEight"
                    android:text="5"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonSix"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@id/buttonNine"
                    android:layout_below="@id/buttonNine"
                    android:text="6"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonOne"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/buttonFour"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonTwo"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@id/buttonEight"
                    android:layout_below="@id/buttonFive"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonThree"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@id/buttonNine"
                    android:layout_below="@id/buttonSix"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonDot"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/buttonOne"
                    android:text="."
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonZero"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@id/buttonEight"
                    android:layout_below="@id/buttonTwo"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonEqual"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@id/buttonNine"
                    android:layout_below="@id/buttonThree"
                    android:text="="
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonDivide"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@id/buttonNine"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonNine"
                    android:text="/"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonMultiply"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@id/buttonSix"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonSix"
                    android:text="*"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonSubtract"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@id/buttonThree"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonThree"
                    android:text="-"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonAdd"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@id/buttonEqual"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonEqual"
                    android:text="+"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonClear"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@id/buttonAdd"
                    android:layout_below="@id/buttonAdd"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="C"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonParentesis1"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@id/buttonDot"
                    android:layout_below="@id/buttonAdd"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="("
                    android:textSize="20sp" />


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonParentesis2"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@id/buttonZero"
                    android:layout_below="@id/buttonAdd"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text=")"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />



        </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Supongo que tienes una base de Java. Te aconsejo reducir el problema para encontrar una solución y como el desarrollo de la aplicación Android añade complejidad y mucha, trataría primero de probar la lógica de las operaciones que crees que te están fallando con Java en un entorno como Netbeans o Eclipse. No necesitas pulsar teclas, solo tener las operaciones. Cuando veas que funciona llévalo al Android Studio.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Te da error porque en ninguna parte del codigo programaste el comportamiento de parentesis (). Cuando intentas parsear un double en el metodo computeCalculation() que tiene uno o mas parentesis, te dará Exception porque solo podes parsear números y un punto. 
Debes programas la lógica de los parentesis y separarlos de los sumandos.